# Selecting first in each (SQL / PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I tried holding off and looking for answers, but I need your guys' help! I have three tables- category, project, and images. I have it set up so that images are linked to a specific project, and each project has a category. I use two inner joins to do this (is this correct?) What I'm looking to do eventually is have PHP echo out the first image from each project, and then I'll use ajax to load in the rest of the images per project. I've looked at LIMIT and I'm sure there's a way to do it easily with PHP and a for loop, but I'm just stumped! How can I echo out just the first "filename" per project? Thanks in advance!

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `project` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `caption` text NOT NULL,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `project` int(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Query:

```
SELECT i.filename as filename,
          i.project as project_id,
          p.name as project_name,
          c.name as category

FROM images i

INNER JOIN project p
ON i.project = p.id

INNER JOIN category c
ON p.category = c.id
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` the results by a project's id. And welcome to SO.

Comment: When you say "first per project", what do you mean? Ordered by name? By id?

Comment: An observation: `project.id` is defined as `int(11)` while `images.project` as `int(50)` .

Comment: @Linus Kleen Thanks, I'm surprised how fast the help came through! If I `GROUP BY`, wouldn't that just return the images in their groups? ("filename" in each "project")   How would I get only the first filename stored in each group? Thanks!

Comment: @ypercube I guess ordered by id, but I suppose I was thinking, whichever filename is in the first row per project. I'm guessing that means I should've planned this differently?   Thanks for pointing out the int(50)- doesn't make sense!

Comment: Well, in SQL, there is no such thing as *first row*. Rows as stored and retrieved in any order the database wants. Unless you expicitely tell so with `ORDER BY`. And no it doesn't mean you should plan it diferrently. There is SQL solution for whichever order you want to achieve.

Comment: @Strongwings See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you can group your query's results by a specific column / columns.

This query without a `GROUP BY` works better for finding the *first* image within a project:

```
SELECT @pid := `prj_id`, 
   (SELECT MIN(`id`) FROM `images` `i` WHERE `i`.`prj_id` = @pid) `first_img`
FROM `projects`
```

This'll also select projects having no images at all (i.e. `first_img` being `NULL`). A `HAVING` clause filtering these might be necessary.

Comment: I'll be honest, some of this is over my head, but I think I got the gist of it. ;) The query is very helpful! I'm curious about your suggestion on how I should set up the query. So instead of selecting things from the `images` table, I should be selecting all projects first? I guess the order and what exactly I should be INNER JOINING I got lost on. Thanks again- huge help!

Comment: It'll show up on the "edited" history, so I just removed my confusing rant about `INNER JOIN` and so on to leave the actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try DISTINCT at some point:

```
SELECT i.filename as filename,
          i.project as project_id,
          DISTINCT(p.name) as project_name,
          c.name as category

FROM images i

INNER JOIN project p
ON i.project = p.id

INNER JOIN category c
ON p.category = c.id
```

Comment: Wow, that was a totally different way of thinking how to accomplish this. Interesting! So let's say I want to use `DISTINCT` to find each individual project, if I threw a `LIMIT 5` at the end would that work to pick out the first 5 distinct projects?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will only work in MySQL and will give you one (random) filename per project:

```
SELECT i.filename as filename
     , i.project as project_id
     , p.name as project_name
     , c.name as category

  FROM images i
    INNER JOIN project p
      ON i.project = p.id
    INNER JOIN category c
      ON p.category = c.id

  GROUP BY p.id
;
```

ANd this will select the filename with lowest id. I'm sure it can be improved in terms of performance. I definitely need some sleep...

```
SELECT i.filename as filename
     , im.project_id
     , im.project_name
     , im.category

  FROM images i
    INNER JOIN 
    ( SELECT MIN(i.id) as id
           , i.project as project_id
           , p.name as project_name
           , c.name as category
        FROM images i
          INNER JOIN project p
            ON i.project = p.id
          INNER JOIN category c
            ON p.category = c.id
        GROUP BY p.id
    ) AS im
    ON i.id= im.id
;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this :

```
foreach ($Result as $r)
{
echo $r['picture'];
break;
}
```

but that wouldn't be nice. You should use LIMIT in SQL, is there anything wrong with LIMIT?

Comment: you could also use `$r=next($Result);`

Comment: Point also should be about the efficiency of code, not only that it does the job. Programmatic way you guys are trying to achieve in this reply won't make this query resource-efficient.

Comment: Are you blind? Thats exactly what I said after the code. The guy asked for PHP code to do that, I provided that. Then I explained its wrong to do so...

Comment: No, I am not "blind", but I missed that in your "that wouldn't be nice" remark - for that I am sorry. But -1 stays, next time try to be more tactful please.

Comment: Yeah let it stay so that you feel better! :D

Comment: My feelings are irrelevant here :) Its just "Tact is the art of making point without making an enemy" as once, a Great Mind stated.

Comment: @Abius @Shehi  Even a link is fine, but what is the inefficiency with having a PHP foreach? I take it this should be accomplished with only one SQL query, and a simple echo statement or something? Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Lol. Inefficiency is when you fetch 100 rows and dump 99 of them just to get 1 you need, whereas you could write correct query and fetched 1 row you need.

Comment: My 2c here: My reading of the OP's question was how to use LIMIT (or other way) to write the SQL query needed to fetch only the 1 row needed.

Comment: The FAQ to SO states, it is a platform for *"professional and enthusiast programmers"*. There's no mention of flaming around, though. I see a lot of enthusiasm, but definitely no professionalism to both of your comments, @Shehi and @AbiusX.